# How did Frank realize the coup?

Tags: plot-explanation, house-of-cards

So in *House of Cards* episode 7 of season 5, while in the bunker, Frank realizes that it was all a coup against him. I'm confused as to how he realized this. He didn't exchange many words with Claire, yet somehow they figured it out.